# IF with multiple conditions based on a value greater than or less than a given value

Tags: google-sheets, formula, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a formula with multiple conditions in an effort to return a value based on those conditions. The formula I have currently written is only returning one value, F. `=IF(C21<40,"F",IF(OR(C21>40,C21<54,"D",IF(OR(C21>55,C21<69,"C",IF(OR(C21>70,C21<84,"B",IF(OR(C21>84,"A")))))))))`

Visual explanation below:

[image: 1]

```
=IF(C21<40,"F",IF(OR(C21>40,C21<54,"D",IF(OR(C21>55,C21<69,"C",IF(OR(C21>70,C21<84,"B",IF(OR(C21>84,"A")))))))))
```

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to write with IFS: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en

Comment: ifs method returns "no match"

Comment: =IFS(C21>85,"A",C21>70,"B", C21>55,"C", C21>40,"D",C21>0,"F")

Answer (score 1):

Use lookups. In this particular case `XLOOKUP`:

```
=arrayformula(XLOOKUP(A1:A11,$E$1:$E$5,$D$1:$D$5,,-1,-1))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: got it to work with ifs! thanks , all!